# seleccionar id de un elemento del dom con javascript

Tags: php, javascript, dom

En mi archivo js tengo este código para guardar los selectores:

```
    const lista_reuniones = document.querySelector('#boton-eliminar');

eventListeners();

function eventListeners(){    
    listaEmpleados.addEventListener('click', invitarEmpleado);
    lista_reuniones.addEventListener('click', eliminar_reunion);
}


function eliminar_reunion(e){

  if (e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('meeting-plan')){

      const id_reunion = e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-id-reunion');

      console.log(id_reunion);
}
```

En mi archivo php imprimo un div:

```
echo   "<div class='plans' id='meetings-plans'>";
    foreach ($listaReuniones as $reunion) {

        if ($date_meeting > $date_now) { ?>

        //Aquí cojo el id de la reunión con el atributo data-id
        <div class='meeting-plan'  data-id-reunion='<?php echo $reunion->getId() ?>'>
            <ul class="datos-empleado">

                <li>Organizado por: <?php echo $reunion->getIdEmpleadoOrganizador() ?></li>
                <li> Asunto: <?php echo $reunion->getAsunto() ?></li>
                <li>Sala: <?php echo $reunion->getSala() ?></li>
                <li>Fecha: <?php echo $reunion->getFecha() ?></li>
                <li>Comienza: <?php echo $reunion->getInicio() ?></li>
                <li>Termina: <?php echo $reunion->getFin() ?></li>
                <li>Obervaciones: <?php echo $reunion->getObservaciones() ?></li>
                <li>Coste Estimado: <?php echo $reunion->getCosteEstimado() ?></li>
                <li><a href="../views/empleados_asistentes.php?id=<?php echo $reunion->getId() ?>">Ver Invitados</a></li>
                <li><a href="../views/empleado_invitar_vista.php?id=<?php echo $reunion->getId() ?>">Invitar</a></li>
                <li><a href="../views/reunionEditar.php?id=<?php echo $reunion->getId() ?>">Editar</a></li>
                <li id="boton-eliminar"><a href="#">Eliminar</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>

    <?php }
}

    echo "</div>";
```

Estoy intentando coger el id de la reunion a traves del atributo data-id del div, para que al hacer click en

```
<li><a href="#">Eliminar</a></li>
```

Me imprima el id con un console.log ... Pero no hace absolutamente nada...

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ayudarte con tu pregunta he intentado primero abstraer el resultado de lo que tu código PHP produce a un html básico (faltarán datos, pero creo que esto es un buen ejemplo).

```html
<div class="plans" id="meeting-plans">
    <!-- Loop Begin -->
    <div class="meeting-plan" data-id-meeting="meeting1">
        <ul>
            <li>Meeting One</li>
            <!-- No deberías poner ids estáticos en un bucle, mejor utiliza una clase -->
            <li class="meeting-plan-delete"><a href="#">Eliminar</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="meeting-plan" data-id-meeting="meeting2">
        <ul>
            <li>Meeting Two</li>
            <!-- No deberías poner ids estáticos en un bucle, mejor utiliza una clase -->
            <li class="meeting-plan-delete"><a href="#">Eliminar</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="meeting-plan" data-id-meeting="meeting3">
        <ul>
            <li>Meeting Three</li>
            <!-- No deberías poner ids estáticos en un bucle, mejor utiliza una clase -->
            <li class="meeting-plan-delete"><a href="#">Eliminar</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Loop End-->
</div>
```

Ahora, con este ejemplo podemos intentar solucionar tu problema.

En primer lugar, los `eventListener` no queremos añadirlos al propio meeting, sino a cada uno de los botones que se van a generar dentro de los meeting. Tú los llamas por id aunque deberías hacerlo por clase, el ejemplo lo haré por clase.

```
// Recuperamos todos los botones eliminar que hemos introducido en el dom
const meetingList = document.querySelectorAll('.meeting-plan-delete');

// Iteramos sobre meetingList y añadimos un EventListener para click.

meetingList.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', myCallback);
})
```

Con esto tenemos ya un eventListener en cada uno de los elementos que queremos. Ahora definamos el `callback` de nuestro eventListener:

```
function myCallback(event) {
  // Recuperamos todos los 'padres' del elemento.
  const elementPath = e.path;

  // Encontramos de entre todos los padres cuál tiene la clase 'meeting-plan'
  const parentMeeting = elementPath.find(el => el.classList.contains('meeting-plan'));

  /* Aquí va lo que sea que quieras hacer con tu elemento */

}
```

Por último, querías acceder a `data-id-meeting`. A este tipo de propiedades no se accede vía `getAttribute`, sino a través del objeto `dataset`. Dataset recoge los valores de todos los `data-*` almacenándolos en un objeto cuya clave es el nombre que se le da en camelcase, por ejemplo para acceder a `data-my-awesome-attribute` sería `element.dataset.myAwesomeAttribute`.

Con toda esta información te dejo un snippet que puede hacer lo que propones.

```js
const deleteMeetingButtonList = document.querySelectorAll('.meeting-plan-delete');

function deleteMeeting(e) {
  const elementPath = e.path;
  
  const parentMeeting = elementPath.find(el => el.classList.contains('meeting-plan'));
  
  console.log(parentMeeting.dataset.idMeeting);
};


deleteMeetingButtonList.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', deleteMeeting);
})
```

```html
<div class="plans" id="meeting-plans">
    <!-- Loop Begin -->
    <div class="meeting-plan" data-id-meeting="meeting1">
        <ul>
            <li>Meeting One</li>
            <!-- No deberías poner ids estáticos en un bucle, mejor utiliza una clase -->
            <li class="meeting-plan-delete"><a href="#">Eliminar</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="meeting-plan" data-id-meeting="meeting2">
        <ul>
            <li>Meeting Two</li>
            <!-- No deberías poner ids estáticos en un bucle, mejor utiliza una clase -->
            <li class="meeting-plan-delete"><a href="#">Eliminar</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="meeting-plan" data-id-meeting="meeting3">
        <ul>
            <li>Meeting Three</li>
            <!-- No deberías poner ids estáticos en un bucle, mejor utiliza una clase -->
            <li class="meeting-plan-delete"><a href="#">Eliminar</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Loop End-->
</div>
```

Comment: Ya está!!! Muchísimas gracias por el currazo que te has pegado!!

Comment: Solo una duda... ¿Por qué no usar ids? Yo he hecho lo mismo que tú con ids y me funciona perfectamente. Lo hago así porque es una manera de tener claro que cuando manejo clases, estoy tocando css y cuando manejo ids, estoy con javascript...

Comment: El asunto de no usar IDs tiene que ver con HTML, los id, por definición han de ser únicos, si iteras con IDs estaticos tendrás varias veces el mismo ID